# Copy all values List<String> to Jackson JsonGenerator Array directly instead of looping over it

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, jackson2

I am creating a `JSON` file using the `Jackson JsonGenerator` for which I need to add the elements from `List<String>`. This `List` consists of the `JSON Fragments` which needs to be added to my final `JSON` file.

As of now, I am looping over the `List<String>` and adding them to my `Jackson JsonGenerator writeRaw` one-by-one. This is working fine as of now. However, my `List` can have 1000s or more values then I do not wish to loop and add one by one. Rather than that, I am finding a way to directly add the array to the `JsonGeneator` array. I wanted to know if there is a way to directly copy the array something like this:

```
jsonGenerator.writeArray("eventList",eventsList);
```

Following is the code I have currently:

```
public class JacksonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();
        eventsList.add("{\n" + "  \"isA\": \"Customer\",\n" + "  \"name\": \"Rise Against\",\n" + "  \"age\": \"2000\"\n" + "}");
        eventsList.add("{\n" + "  \"isA\": \"Owener\",\n" + "  \"name\": \"Linkin Park\",\n" + "  \"age\": \"2ßß8\"\n" + "}");
        eventsList.add("{\n" + "  \"isA\": \"Customer\",\n" + "  \"name\": \"Breaking Benjamin\",\n" + "  \"age\": \"2005\"\n" + "}");

        StringWriter jsonObjectWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter).useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("schema","2.0");
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("date","2021-06-22");


        //Current Approach
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("eventList");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();

        //Add events from the list one by one
        eventsList.forEach(event -> {
            try {
                jsonGenerator.writeRaw(event + ",");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
        jsonGenerator.close();
        jsonGenerator.flush();

        System.out.println(jsonObjectWriter.toString());
    }
}
```

As you can observe from the above code, I am looping over the `List<String>` and adding them to `JsonGeneator` one-by-one. Can someone please suggest if there is a way to directly add the `List<String>` to `JsonGenerator` so that I can skip the `looping` part.

Something similar is available in `JSONObject` here we can directly add the list:

```
final JSONObject doc = new JSONObject();
doc.put("schemaVersion", 2.0);
final JSONObject eventListAsJson = new JSONObject();
eventListAsJson.put("eventList", eventsList);
doc.put("eventList", eventListAsJson);
```

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: A call like `writeArray("eventList",eventsList);` would probably loop internally anyway so you'd not gain much here. But you could try to build the json string first and then use one call to `writeRaw()`, e.g. `writeRaw(String.join(",", eventsList))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response and your time. This could also help as I do not have to loop here explicitly and everything is taken care of internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Thomas I did the following to add the elements from `LIST` to my `JsonGenerator`:

```
jsonGenerator.writeRaw(String.join(",", eventsList));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    ObjectNode objectNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
    objectNode.put("schema", "2.0");
    objectNode.put("date", "2021-06-22");

    ArrayNode arrayNode = new ObjectMapper().createArrayNode();
    for (String s : eventsList) {
        arrayNode.add(new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, ObjectNode.class));
    }
    objectNode.set("eventList", arrayNode);

    System.out.println(objectNode.toPrettyString());
```

Comment: It would be good if you'd add at least some explanation of what your code is meant to do and how it would answer the question. You might also want to address potential performance issues, e.g. [`ObjectMapper` is thread-safe](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) and thus could and should be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the response but as mentioned by @Thomas some explanation of what you are trying to convey would provide more clarity on the answer as you are using a completely different logic than what I have requested in the question. Also, I believe this is not the right answer that I am looking for.